# Integration by parts loop with coefficient

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I leant that when the integral appears on the right side of the equation, it can be transferred accross to the left side, as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281171/how-to-integrate-when-integration-by-parts-never-ends), but I'm trying to learn how to do this if there is a coefficient with the integral on the RHS. For example:

\begin{align}\int e^{-int}\sin(t)\,dt&=\frac{i}{n}e^{-int}\sin(t)-\int\frac{i}{n}e^{-int}\cos(t)\,dt \\
&=\frac{i}{n}e^{-int}\sin(t)-\left(-\frac{1}{n^2}e^{-int}\cos(t)-\int\frac{1}{n^2}e^{-int}\sin(t)\,dt\right)\end{align}

I can see that the integral appears on the RHS, and normally this could be transferred across to the LHS, but I'm not sure of how it all works with the $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\int e^{-int} \sin(t) \, dt
= \frac{i}{n}e^{-int}\sin(t) + \frac{1}{n^2}e^{-int}\cos(t) + \frac{1}{n^2} \int e^{-int}\sin(t)
$$

So,
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \int e^{-int} \sin(t) \, dt
= \frac{i}{n}e^{-int}\sin(t) + \frac{1}{n^2}e^{-int}\cos(t)
$$
i.e.
$$
\int e^{-int} \sin(t) \, dt 
= \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{-1} \left( \frac{i}{n}e^{-int}\sin(t) + \frac{1}{n^2}e^{-int}\cos(t) \right) \\
= \frac{n^2}{n^2-1} \left( \frac{i}{n}e^{-int}\sin(t) + \frac{1}{n^2}e^{-int}\cos(t) \right) \\
= \frac{in}{n^2-1}e^{-int}\sin(t) + \frac{1}{n^2-1}e^{-int}\cos(t) \\
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you denote $\color{#df0000}{I := \int e^{- i n t} \sin t \,dt}$, the equation becomes
$$\color{#df0000}{I} = \frac{1}{n} e^{-int} \sin t + \frac{1}{n^2} e^{-int} \cos t + \frac{1}{n^2} \color{#df0000}{I} + C$$ for a constant $C$ of integration. Now, solve for $\color{#df0000}{I}$, which we can do iff $n \neq \pm 1$.

**Remark** Alternatively you can evaluate this integral by writing $\sin t = \frac{1}{2 i} (e^{i t} - e^{-i t})$ and distributing to get a linear combination of the integrals $\int e^{-i(n \mp 1)t} dt$---this formulation makes it clearer why the cases $n = \pm 1$ are qualitatively different from the case of generic $n$.

Comment: Even in the OP formalism, you can understand the difference if you write down a definite integral with one limit fixed, and understand the $n=\pm 1$ case as a limit. The "algebraic weirdness" of this extra factor of $t$ is caused by the fact that the way we usually would write down, say, $\int e^{it} \sin(bt) dt$, isn't actually "the same antiderivative" for each $b \neq \pm 1$.

Comment: @Ian I agree---what I mean by the last sentence is that for $n = \pm 1$ respectively the integral is just $\int dt$, which cannot be handled by the usual rule $\int e^{at} dt = \frac{1}{a} e^{at} + C$, and that this failure is perhaps easier to see than the one in, e.g., $\int e^{it} \sin (bt) \,dt$.